# Wide column pagination in CQL table

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Let say i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE comments
(
    postId uuid,
    commentId timeuuid,
    postedBy text,
    postedById uuid,
    text text,
    blocked boolean,
    anonymous boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY(postId, commentId)
)
```

How can I perform wide column pagination on this table something like :

`SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postId = '123' AND commentId > '34566'`

I was going through [Automatic Paging](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0) but confused with three approaches mentioned in this document that which should I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare field for timeuuid, you need to using the expression like below:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postId = '123' AND commentId > maxTimeuuid('2013-08-01 15:05-0500')
```

Comment: how it is doing pagination ? what is ` maxTimeuuid('2013-08-01 15:05-0500')`?

Comment: TimeUUID is generated based on time, so  maxTimeuuid('2013-08-01 15:05-0500') is the max UUID of the time point ("'2013-08-01 15:05-0500"). the expression select all record which UUID is generated  after that point of time("'2013-08-01 15:05-0500")

Comment: wht i am saying is that how will i specify my "next starting point " along with the number of column that it should fetch. You have fixed it with `2013-08-01 15:05-0500`

Comment: "2013-08-01 15:05-0500" is just a time format string, you could generated that time point as you need. You may using datetime package..

Comment: Of course, you could add or not add "limit" after that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've received the `ResultSet` from the `execute` method, you should be able to simply iterate over it using the [`iterator` method](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#iterator()). Pagination will happen automatically, based on the value specified in [`setFetchSize`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) or the default value of 5000.